# How do I reload the editing style of a UITableViewCell without losing focus?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a table with custom UITableViewCells which have UITextFields in them; basically, I'm mimicing the editing view of Apple's Contacts app.  Once the user starts typing in the text field in the bottom row, I insert one beneath it.  Everything's great except that the one the user is typing in doesn't display the delete indicator when they start typing.  I can reload it and it will, but the text field in the cell loses first responder status until the user clicks again.  I've tried calling [currTextField becomeFirstResponder] after but it doesn't work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked that it is not a resize problem? If you type away does it look like the text is getting off the screen before the text field starts to scroll?